# Linked list value double_up() method causing TypeError

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in python and trying to create a method that doubles the value of each element in the linked list. This method updates the `LinkedList` object and it does not return anything.

I'm getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Node' and 'int'`.
Would anybody able to give me some tips on how to fix it?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    def get_next(self):
        return self.next
    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data
    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0
    def add(self, item): 
        new_node = Node(item, self.head)
        self.head = new_node
        self.count += 1
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0
    def size(self):
        return self.count
    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current.data == item:
                return True
        current = current.next
        return False
    def remove(self, item): #change this method to update self.count
        found = False
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current is not None and not found:
            if current.data == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.next
        if found:
            if previous == None:
                self.head= current.next
            else:
                previous.set_next(current.next)
            self.count -= 1
    def count(self):
        return len(self)
    def __str__(self):
        new_str = ""
        if self.count != 0:
            curr = self.head
            while curr is not None:
                new_str += str(curr.data) + " -> "
                curr = curr.next
            new_str += "None"
        return new_str
    def remove_from_head(self):
        data = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.count -=1
        return data
    def double_up(self):
        while self.head.data != None:
            self.head.data = self.head.data * 2
            self.head.data = self.head.next
        
        
fruit = LinkedList()
fruit.add('cherry')
fruit.add('banana')
fruit.add('apple')
print(fruit)
fruit.double_up()
print(fruit)
```

Expected output:

```
apple -> banana -> cherry -> None
appleapple -> bananabanana -> cherrycherry -> None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not traversing the linked list properly — you need to do it similarly to how the `search()` and `remove()` methods do it — i.e. like so:

```
    def double_up(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            current.data = current.data * 2
            current = current.next
```

Note you could write the `while` loop as shown below, which is a little more succinct:

```
        while current:
            ...
```